# Simplify numerous array declarations in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I'm totally new to programming so please bare with me.
I got 24 arrays of the same size and I have to call 2 functions with each array as a parameter. So first I tried it like that:

```
int array1[1023];
int array2[1023];
int array3[1023];
...
int array24[1023];

generateCode(array1, 2, 6);
generateCode(array2, 3, 7);
...
generateCode(array24, 4, 6);

calculate(input, array1, 1);
calculate(inpute, array2, 2);
...
calculate(input, array24, 24);
```

It works that way but it looks horrible. So my question is how can I simplify that? I googled for hours and I think I need something like a multidimensional array. But these things are messing up my mind on a different level :(
Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe `int arrays[24][1023]`?

Comment: int array[24][1023]; declare like this and then iterate each rows and pass the values that needed in function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could declare an array of array of int bit like this :

```
int array[24][1023];

generateCode(array[0], 2, 6);
generateCode(array[1], 3, 7);
...
generateCode(array[23], 4, 6); // dunno if you pick random values or if you can make a loop which will do the stuff you want

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    calculate(input, array[i], i + 1); // dunno what does third parameter do so i've put i +1 for tht correspond to your exemple's values but maybe you want something else ;)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have arrays of integers like

```
int array1[SIZE];
...
int arrayN[SIZE];
```

when you can declare an array of the arrays like

```
int * array[] = { array1, ..., arrayN };
```

and then call functions in a loop like

```
const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
{
    generateCode( array[i], value1, value2 );
}
```